# autosum checkbox

Tags: android

So the thing I am trying to accomplish should be exactly like this : http://www.javascriptbank.com/simple-javascript-auto-sum-with-checkboxes.html/en/

Unfortunately im not shure if thats even possible so I would appreciate any kind of help or idea . Thanks in advance.Some thing that i have so far:

```
CheckBox chkone;
CheckBox chktwo;
CheckBox chkthree;
TextView tv;
OnClickListener checkBoxListener;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    chkone = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk1);
    chktwo = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk2);
    thkthree = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.chk3);


checkBoxListener = new OnClickListener() {

        //@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

            if (chkone.isChecked())
            {   
              // something

            }

        }
    };

    chkone.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    chktwo.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
    chkthree.setOnClickListener(checkBoxListener);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement the `CompoundButton's` `OnCheckedChangeListener` interface instead, to get notifications about the checkbox's state changes.

Assuming that you didn't extend the `CheckBox` class to ease your work by storing a numeric value somewhere, you need to parse the label (text) of the checkbox in order to access it's value, and based on the checked state increase / decrease the sum:

```
private TextView sumText;
private float currentSum = 0;
private final OnCheckedChangeListener checkBoxListener = 
    new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked)
            currentSum += getNumber(buttonView);
        else
            currentSum -= getNumber(buttonView);
        // TODO: you need to initialize this TextView in your
        // onCreate method!
        sumText.setText(Float.toString(currentSum));
    }
};

private float getNumber(final CompoundButton chk)
{
    try
    {
        return Float.parseFloat(chk.getText().toString());
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Note**, that for this to work as you expect it, you should modify the `getNumber` method to retrieve the values that is actually under that `CheckBox` instance!